# How to prioritize the JOB NOTIFICATION plugin to run first in post build actions

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a setup in my job config. I just want to execute some downstream jobs after job notification plugin invoked from POST Build actions. But downstream jobs always trigger first and followed by job notification plugin is invoked.

Is there any way to run first job notification plugin and followed by downstream job execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flexible Publish from Jenkins. It maintains the order of execution of post-build actions and also allows you to use a publisher more than once in a build.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/flexible-publish

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin

Comment: I dont find the plugin in jenkins.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you running? It should be available under 'Avaliable' tag in Manage Plugins. You can search for 'Flexible Publish'.
The minimum Jenkins version required for this plugin is 1.425